# Prove that a function from a power set to the set of all functions between two sets is bijective

Tags: analysis

I am reading Amann's book of Analysis I and I am trying to prove the following:
For each non empty set X , the function
 P(X)↦{0,1}<sup>x</sup>，A↦X<sub>A</sub> 
is bijective

Where P(X) according to the Book is the power set of X , X<sub>A</sub> is the characteristic function of A defined:
X<sub>A</sub>:X↦{0,1} ,x↦❴1 if x∈A or 0 if x∉A❵

And Y<sup>x</sup>  can be written as Funct(X,Y) and denotes the set of all functions from X to Y.

Attempt of solution:
I know I have to prove that is surjective and Injective , for the first y tried to show that the image of the function equals {0,1}<sup>x</sup> but I don't know how to choose  the elements and show both contentions, for the second I have the same problem I am not sure if I am working with sets , functions or set valued functions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's show that $\Phi$ (your function) is injective :

Take $A,B\in P(X)$ such that $\Phi(A) = \Phi(B)$, i.e. $\chi_A = \chi_B$. We'll prove that $A=B$

Let $x\in A$, then $\chi_A(x) = 1$, so $\chi_B(x) = 1$ and $x\in B$

Let $x\in B$, then $\chi_B(x) = 1$, so $\chi_A(x) = 1$ and $x\in A$

This show that $A=B$, and that $\Phi$ is injective.

Now, let's show that $\Phi$ is surjective :

Let $f\in \{0,1\}^X$, then define $A = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = 1\}$

It's easy to see that $\Phi(A) = \chi_A = f$, and then $\Phi$ is surjective

Comment: thanks for your answer ,In your proof you only considered the case x∈A but the other  case has the same reasoning right？

Comment: @salvadorlazaro : I proved that $x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B$ and that $x\in B \Rightarrow x\in A$, so this prove that $x\in A \Leftrightarrow x\in B$, and this imply that $A=B$

Comment: Oh yes You are right sorry I misunderstood , now I get the idea thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As a big hint, I will give you the function
$$\phi:\mathcal{P}(X)\longrightarrow\{0,1\}^X$$
that you must consider. To an element $A\in\mathcal{P}(X)$, that is, a subset $A\subseteq X$, we associate the map
$$\phi(A):X\longrightarrow \{0,1\}$$
given by
$$\phi(A)(x)=\cases{0&if $x\notin A$\\1&if $x\in A$}.$$
The inverse of this map $\phi$ is given by associating to a map $X\to\{0,1\}$ (i.e. an element of $\{0,1\}^X$) the preimage of $1$.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I understood now that I am working with set valued functions but I didn't get what you meant in your last line , about the inverse of the map , could you explain it in other words please?

Comment: @salvadorlazaro Hi. Given a map $f:X\to\{0,1\}$, you can associate to it a subset of $X$ simply by taking $f^{-1}(\{1\})$. This association is the invers application to $\phi$. Obviously, you have to prove that, but it's not hard at all.